# Convert ant script(xml) to gradle script

Tags: xml, gradle, ant, build.gradle, hipi

I need help converting an Ant script to a Gradle script.
Here is the code for the ant script:
From http://dinesh-malav.blogspot.my/2015/05/image-processing-using-opencv-on-hadoop.html

[ant script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq9UA.png)

and I need the gradle script that convert from the above ant script to add inside the below gradle script:

[gradle script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhe7R.png)

Anyone know how to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: If you just want to directly copy the logic from your Ant script, Gradle has full Ant support through its AntBuilder: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html . If you're trying to create a Gradle script that uses standard Gradle conventions to accomplish the same goals as your Ant script, I'm afraid there's no simple answer. That's just some engineering work you'll have to do on your own.

Comment: Thank you for provide guide. For my situation, I already have the build.gradle, now I need to add the ant script part to the gradle file. So is that can use the AntBuilder?

Comment: Can you provide me guide on how to add the an script to the build.gradle? Because when I am using the ant.importBuilder,it show around 100 errors.